# I am trying to connect my postgres db but I am getting this socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, postgresql, model-view-controller

Im trying to connect the database and to create tables by models:

```
importing

DB = PostgresEngine(config={
    'host': '5433',
    'database': 'postgres',
    'user': 'postgres',
    'password': ''
})

engine = engine_finder()
engine.start_connection_pool()

class Admins(Table):

    login = Varchar()
    password = Varchar()
```

There are other models in here and:

```
engine.close_connection_pool()
```

But Im getting this error:[Screen_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezw3j.png) [Screen_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAmO5.png)

Is there any bug in framework or Im doing something wrong?

Comment: "host" should be the name or IP address of the database server.  You seem to have entered what might be the value for "port".

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thnx a lot! it was stupid! :D